# Demerits of oscilloscope performing measurement and math functions on displayed data

Tags: oscilloscope

I came across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vaOJanBYlos) on youtube.

**Summary of the video:** Tektronix uses measurement and maths functions on the acquired data whereas Keysight uses these functions on the displayed data. This leads to a different measurement value when you start zooming in the displayed data on keysight oscilloscope. Tektronix concludes that this is inferior method of measurement. Tek good, keysight bad sort of stuff.

I want to understand whether keysight's method is flawed in practical use cases? If so, why/how will a company do such a blunder? Or is tektronix just blowing it out of proportion?

Answer (score 1):

I had to mess with some Keysight and Rigol equipment and came across the same thing, though I thought Keysight did look at all the data and Rigol didn't so maybe there are some Keysight models that look at all data, not just displayed. Tektronix's version is preferred, though Keysight makes pretty good equipment and probably shouldn't lag behind too much for most applications. I had one of the newer models on loan, so perhaps they have improved their equipment.

I cannot recall if it is was just the Rigol or also the Keysight, but I think the screen resolution actually did matter a lot on measurements and could become a hindrance when the measurement functions only used the display data. With a low resolution (when zoomed out), the measurement function had less dynamic range to work with if I recall, which ended up affecting things when trying to view an ADC's output and voltage steps. Not good, but wasn't critical for my purposes. I would say the video does show some pretty bad issues with the Keysight though, that was quite a bit of fluctuation.